# BeforeItemMove event not fired in Outlook when item is deleted on remote machine

Tags: c#, outlook, exchange-server, outlook-addin

I am developing an outlook add-in, where I have events which will be fired when an item is deleted from drafts. So when I delete the files from my drafts on my machine, the `BeforeItemMove` event is fired.

But here comes the interesting case. Additionally I also have a VM, where I have outlook installed and logged in to the same account. So my drafts are synced there as well. When I delete a draft on the VM, after some time the draft gets deleted on my system as well. But this time it doesn't fire the `BeforeItemMove` event on my local machine. What am I missing? Is it even dependent on Exchange? Or is a new event for folder update that I should subscribe to? Below is my code.

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder draftsFolder = null;
    draftsFolder = nameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderDrafts) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Folder;
    draftsFolder.BeforeItemMove += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolderEvents_12_BeforeItemMoveEventHandler(BeforeItemMoveFromDrafts);
```

The event method is

```
private void BeforeItemMoveFromDrafts(object Item, MAPIFolder MoveTo, ref bool Cancel)
{

...

}
```

PS. I also have a reference to the folder object, so that is not the issue.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding the [BeforeItemMove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869445.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event shouldn't be fired on another machines. It is fired  when an item is about to be moved or deleted from a folder, either as a result of user action or through program code. The code should be run against the local Outlook instance.

P.S. Make sure that the source object is declared at the global scope to prevent it from swiping by the garbage collector.

Comment: Isn't there any way to know if my items are moved when my folders are updated?

Comment: Try to handle the [FolderChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869140.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event. Also you may consider keeping the list of items and check them after each sync with the server, see [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/).

Comment: But, how do I know when my folders are synced? Is there any event for that?

Comment: Even FolderChange event is fired as a result of user action and program code! :/